# Linq expression with multiple joins with condition in each join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have number of tables like:

1. User_cs
2. UserEducation_cs
3. Experience

following is the database diagram[image]

What I need is users info

1. their basic info from User_cs
2. Their last education(i.e. latest degree that they acquired)
3. Where they are currently working(if user is NOT working then) fields in Experience_cs will be NULL.

I so far able to do following but I am having trouble 1) how in the middle of lamda expression I do (IsWorking==true) and following that join to next table. Following is my expression

```
   List<Models.UserInfo> v = context.User_cs
            .Join(context.UserEducation_cs, u => u.UserName, ue => ue.UserName, (u, ue) => new UserEducation_cs
            {
                UserName = ue.UserName,
                EducationId = ue.EducationId,
                StartDate = ue.StartDate,
                EndDate = ue.EndDate
            }).
            Join(context.Education_cs, ue => ue.EducationId, e => e.EducationId, (ue, e) => new
            {
                UserName = ue.UserName,
                EducationId = ue.EducationId,
                StartDate = ue.StartDate,
                EndDate = ue.EndDate,
                Title = e.Title,
                Major = e.Major,
                MajorDetails = e.MajorDetails,
                Info = e.Info
            }).
            Join(context.Experiences, lst => lst.UserName, ex => ex.UserName, (lst, ex) => new Models.UserInfo
            {
                UserName = ex.UserName,
                EducationId = lst.EducationId,
                StartDate = lst.StartDate,
                EndDate = lst.EndDate,
                Title = lst.Title,
                Major = lst.Major,
                MajorDetails = lst.MajorDetails,
                Info = lst.Info,
                IsWorking = ex.IsWorking,
                StartDate_ex=ex.StartedDate,                    
            }).
            Where(iw => iw.IsWorking == true).ToList();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is wrong with your current expression, exactly?

Comment: its just doing join right now, but I want is to have conditions that I need to check 1)IsWorking in Experience_cs, should be true 2) in Education_cs, only lastest LastDate rows should be included in join

Comment: I think you have to use a `.GroupJoin()`. In that case the right side is not a single element, but an IEnumerable of all matching elements. Then you can apply further conditions or filters on that sequence to grab the desired  element(s) (e.g. one, multiple or none) you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question completely. I think you need to filter your lists before applying the (inner) join to them. To get only newest `Education_cs` entry for each `User_cs` I suppose you could use grouping. Also, I have not exactly tested this code:

```
List<Models.UserInfo> v = context.User_cs
        .Join(context.UserEducation_cs, u => u.UserName, ue => ue.UserName, (u, ue) => new UserEducation_cs
        {
            UserName = ue.UserName,
            EducationId = ue.EducationId,
            StartDate = ue.StartDate,
            EndDate = ue.EndDate
        }).
        Join(context.Education_cs.GroupBy(q => q.UserName).Select(q => q.OrderByDescending(w => w.StartDate).First()), 
             ue => ue.EducationId, e => e.EducationId, (ue, e) => new
        {
            UserName = ue.UserName,
            EducationId = ue.EducationId,
            StartDate = ue.StartDate,
            EndDate = ue.EndDate,
            Title = e.Title,
            Major = e.Major,
            MajorDetails = e.MajorDetails,
            Info = e.Info
        }).
        Join(context.Experiences.Where(ex => ex.IsWorking), lst => lst.UserName, ex => ex.UserName, (lst, ex) => new Models.UserInfo
        {
            UserName = ex.UserName,
            EducationId = lst.EducationId,
            StartDate = lst.StartDate,
            EndDate = lst.EndDate,
            Title = lst.Title,
            Major = lst.Major,
            MajorDetails = lst.MajorDetails,
            Info = lst.Info,
            IsWorking = ex.IsWorking,
            StartDate_ex=ex.StartedDate,                    
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: you understood it right, I also want to select only rows from experience_cs where user is currently working

Comment: @Alex, isn't that what `IsWorking` does? If not, how do you determine that?

Comment: for some reason  UserName = ue.FirstOrDefault().UserName...,is working. are u forgot to include FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: @Alex, you mean in second `Join` you are getting a collection? `First` after `OrderByDescending` should have flatten the groups to single (newest) elements, but maybe I'm missing something. Also, I have just now noticed that you could apply the same grouping and selection in the first `Join` instead of the second one (as it is now, the first `Join` does nothing).